# Sakila -> insert into Film ( mysql WorkBench )

Tags: mysql

I'm trying put a new row in table sakila. film, but I can't see it in the table, I think that not exist, but when execute this statement Works correctly, I don't know what happened

```
INSERT INTO `sakila`.`film`
(
`title`,
`description`,
`release_year`,
`language_id`,
`original_language_id`,
`rental_duration`,
`rental_rate`,
`length`,
`replacement_cost`,
`rating`,
`special_features`,
`last_update`)
VALUES( 'GUSANO' ,'GUSANO' ,2006,1,1,3,4.99,4 ,19.99, 'G','Trailers','2006-02-15 04:34:33.0');
```

Result :

```
21:52:44    INSERT INTO `sakila`.`film` ( `film_id`, `title`, `description`, `release_year`, `language_id`, `original_language_id`, `rental_duration`, `rental_rate`, `length`, `replacement_cost`, `rating`, `special_features`, `last_update`) VALUES( 10010, 'GUSANO' ,'GUSANO' ,2006,1,1,3,4.99,4 ,19.99, 'G','Trailers','2006-02-15 04:34:33.0')   1 row(s) affected   0.015 sec
```

#### Image insert :

[image]

#### Image select :

[image]

Comment: So how are you trying to get it? My guess is that you are not connected directly to this database and are trying to fetch it like `select ... from film....` if you explicit added the database name to the insert, do the same for the select `select ..... from sakila.film ....`

Comment: Not connected ?????? I use to get values : select * from sakila.film, but I can't see a new insert  as example the row "GUSANO" not exist.

Comment: I said not connected to that database. A mysql instance holds many database yours "sakila" is one of then. For instance in a fresh install you have mysql, test and information_schema. If you tried  `select * from sakila.film` it means that the insert command was not persisted which means that your connection is not in autocommit mode. Try to run the insert command and then run `commit;` and then try the select command again. Also, when you connect to mysql run `use sakila;` that will tell mysql that all commands must be executed in that database.

Comment: Another thing that may be happening is some kind of trigger validation which is avoiding the insert command. Try to check if that table `sakila.film` has any trigger associated to it.

Comment: Also, as per you images you are relying on the database order. There is no garante  that the database will show the new registry at the end if you doesn't use an order by command. Try `select * from sakila.film where title = 'GUSANO'` and see if it appears.